# About font loading issues

Tags: css

My website has an issue i.e. fonts are not loading first i don't know why font is loading very slow i used @fontface for fonts 
Check it out http://www.yellowandred.in/newTest/jobs.php

Comment: Accept answers to older questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the path of the fonts i think its not linked correctly...

Font Path:-

http://www.yellowandred.in/newTest/fonts/Avenir%20LT%20input65%20Medium.ttf

http://www.yellowandred.in/newTest/fonts/Neutura%20Light_0.otf

I recommend to use font face generator:- **[Font Face Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)**

or use **[Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts)**

Comment: No SaurabhLP its working fine link:- yellowandred.in/newTest/fonts/Neutura%20Regular_0.otf

Comment: But the site you have provided is signaling to that links about, check the website while opening firebug...

Answer (score 0):

Thank You **SaurabhLP** Font Face Generator worked
CODE:-

---

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'UniversLTStd47CnLtBold';
src: url('../fonts/universltstd-boldcn_0-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/universltstd-boldcn_0-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/universltstd-boldcn_0-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/universltstd-boldcn_0-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/universltstd-boldcn_0-webfont.svg#UniversLTStd47CnLtBold') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}